# Find the three largest elements in an array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o, bubble-sort

> Sample input: [141, 1, 17, -7, -17, -27, 18, 541, 8, 7, 7]
>
> Sample output: [18, 141, 541]

My Code

```
class Program {
     public static int[] findThreeLargestNumbers(int[] array) {
       int j = array.length;
       while(j>= array.length-3){
           for(int i = 0; i<j-1; i++){
               if(array[i]>=array[i+1]){
                   int temp = array[i];
                   array[i] = array[i+1];
                   array[i+1] = temp;
               }
           }
           j--;
       }
       int [] result = new int [3];
       result[0] = array[array.length-3];
       result[1] = array[array.length-2];
       result[2] = array[array.length-1];
       return result;
    }
}
```

I figured I can do bubble sort "3" times since I only care about the 3 largest elements and then exit. I know a traditional bubble sort algorithm is O(N^2). However does my modified algorithm have a better time complexity of O(N) since my while loop only runs 3 times and my for loops runs for N elements making is O(3N) hence O(N) ??

I just need help understanding the time complexity on this rather than the solution which is quite easy.

Comment: Another solution might be build a `max-heap`, the next largest remaining element is always at top. Building the heap takes `O(n*lg(n))`, and each time remove the top element takes `O(lg(n))`.

Comment: Yes but it would take extra space though? In my case I have constant space time complexity.

Comment: No, your array will be converted to a max-heap and than you can apply pop operation. And your code is perfect. You can also achieve answer in O(n) + single traversal. Just use three variables and iterate over array. The main task will be to implement the comparator inside loop. Its easy just do some pen paper work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, your algorithm makes about `3N` comparisons and has `O(N)` complexity.

It is better than full bubble sort because algo performs only partial sorting, the rest remains unsorted.

But note that complexity is linear for **fixed** number of largest elements (here 3). If you need to select say `n/3` largest ones - this approach becomes quadratic, and you'd rather choose another kind of partial sorting (for example, algo based on Quicksort partition or binary heap one)